# Change sound scheme in windows via Windows Registry

Tags: windows, windows-registry

How can I change sound scheme to "no sound" for existing user by editing registry? I'm making a .reg file with all tweaks I need on freshly installed windows but I'm stuck with changing sound scheme.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Changing the scheme is relatively easy. However, you then have to *apply* the new scheme, which is a bit more involved.

The "No Sounds" scheme has the name `.None`; you can see this by exploring `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Names`.

The selected scheme is at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes`, which defaults to `.Default`. So you can set the selected scheme by changing this to `.None`:

```powershell
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\AppEvents\Schemes -Name "(Default)" -Value ".None" -Force | Out-Null
```

This will (technically) set the selected scheme, which you can verify by going to your Sounds settings and see that the `No Sounds` scheme is selected. However, the event sounds will still play, and that is because the selected scheme has not been *applied*.

To apply a sounds scheme, the appropriate action is:

- For each app event matching `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\*\*`, copy the subkey for the new scheme name over the subkey called `.Current`.

As an example, to apply the No Sounds scheme to the System Exclamation event, you would copy `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\SystemExclamation\.None` over `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\SystemExclamation\.Current`.

However, in your case, you can just clear out all the values, since you're applying a "no sounds" theme. This can be accomplished by an one-liner:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path "HKCU:\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps" | Get-ChildItem | Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.PSChildName -eq ".Current"} | Set-ItemProperty -Name "(Default)" -Value ""
```

Step by step:

- `Get-ChildItem -Path "HKCU:\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps"` gets all apps.
- `Get-ChildItem` gets all app events.
- `Get-ChildItem` gets all app event sound settings for each scheme.
- `Where-Object {$_.PSChildName -eq ".Current"}` selects all the app event sound settings that are currently applied.
- `Set-ItemProperty -Name "(Default)" -Value ""` clears those sound settings.

---

For a bit more detail:

It appears that the keys under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps` are the apps, with their default value being a display string. The ones on my system are `.Default` ("Windows"), `Explorer` ("File Explorer"), and `sapisvr` ("Speech Recognition").

The keys under each app key are the app events for that app.

The keys under each app event key are the sounds to play for each sound scheme. So `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\SystemExclamation\.None` is the sound to play for Windows' System Exclamation when using the No Sounds scheme, and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\SystemExclamation\.Default` is the sound to play for Windows' System Exclamation when using the Windows Default scheme.

In addition, there's a `.Current` key at this level that is the actual sound that is played. Presumably, when you select a new scheme in the UI, it copies each of the settings individually over the `.Current` value.

Comment: You could shorten the two stacked gci's and the where to => `Get-ChildItem -Path "HKCU:\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\*\*\.current"` as `Get-ChildItem` allows wildcards on multiple levels.

Answer (score 0):

I just created this script. Use at your own risk;

```
if (-Not (Test-Path 'HKCU:\AppEvents\Schemes\Names\.None'))
{ 
    New-Item -Path 'HKCU:\AppEvents\Schemes\Names' -Name '.None'
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\AppEvents\Schemes\Names\.None' -Name '(Default)' -Type 'String' -Value 'No Sounds'
}

Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKCU:\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default' | Select Name | ForEach-Object {
    $thing = $_.Name -replace "HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "HKCU:"
    $fullnun = "$thing\.None"
    if (-Not (Test-Path $thing))
    {
        New-Item -Path $thing -Name '.None'
        echo "$thing\.None created"
    } else {
        echo "$thing\.None already existed"
    }

    if (Test-Path($fullnun))
    {
        New-ItemProperty -Path $fullnun -Name '(Default)' -Type 'String' -Value ''
    }
}

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'hkcu:\AppEvents\Schemes' -Name "(Default)" -Type "String" -Value ".None"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me on Windows 10 build 14393

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for setting Sound Schemes to 'NO SOUND'

```
Write-Host " Setting Sound Schemes to 'No Sound' .." -foregroundcolor Gray -backgroundcolor black

$Path = "HKCU:\AppEvents\Schemes"

$Keyname = "(Default)"

$SetValue = ".None"

$TestPath = Test-Path $Path
if (-Not($TestPath -eq $True)) {
   Write-Host " Creating Folder.. " -foregroundcolor Gray -backgroundcolor black
   New-item $path -force
}

if (Get-ItemProperty -path $Path -name $KeyName -EA SilentlyContinue) {

   $Keyvalue = (Get-ItemProperty -path $Path).$keyname

   if ($KeyValue -eq $setValue) {

       Write-Host " The Registry Key Already Exists. " -foregroundcolor green -backgroundcolor black


   }
   else {

       Write-Host " Changing Key Value.. " -foregroundcolor Gray -backgroundcolor black

       New-itemProperty -path $Path -Name $keyname -value $SetValue -force # Set 'No Sound' Schemes
       Get-ChildItem -Path "HKCU:\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps" | # Apply 'No Sound' Schemes
        Get-ChildItem |
        Get-ChildItem |
        Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -eq ".Current" } |
        Set-ItemProperty -Name "(Default)" -Value ""

       Write-Host " The Registry Key Value Changed Sucessfully. " -foregroundcolor green -backgroundcolor black
   }

}
else {

   Write-Host " Creating Registry Key.. " -foregroundcolor Gray -backgroundcolor black

   New-itemProperty -path $Path -Name $keyname -value $SetValue -force
   Get-ChildItem -Path "HKCU:\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps" |
       Get-ChildItem |
       Get-ChildItem |
       Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -eq ".Current" } |
       Set-ItemProperty -Name "(Default)" -Value ""


   Write-Host " The Registry Key Created Sucessfully. " -foregroundcolor green -backgroundcolor black
}
```