# Setting Sound Scheme to "No Sounds" consistently for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I prefer to pick `No Sounds` as my Sound Scheme, but my Windows 10 machine with Build 1809 *keeps setting things back to* `Windows Default`, which is the other option in the drop-down menu.

Is there a way to set such Sound Scheme setting to `No Sound` consistently? Say, through some "Task" via the Task Scheduler?

I found the following questions relevant:

- [Change sound scheme in windows via Windows Registry](https://superuser.com/questions/1300539/change-sound-scheme-in-windows-via-register) ==> Yet, it looks like a lot of code to me;
- [How to turn off all the beep sounds?](https://superuser.com/questions/5017/how-to-turn-off-all-the-beep-sounds) ==> this post assumes a stable `No Sound` setting.

[image: Desired setting]

Comment: Windows settings seem to be stable by themselves, unless someone goes in and change it. In my case, it was the admin policy for my user account that kept changing the Sound Scheme back to "Windows Default".

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue - my SYSTEM SOUNDS were muted:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/sound-scheme-not-working/b694163b-7a47-44d9-9986-2e7c535af83d

Windows key (search) -> Sound Mixer Options: check System Sounds