# Is it possible to write a script that modifies the windows system sound settings?

Tags: windows-10, system-sounds

Is there a way to set the "Asterisk" and "Exclamation" event window sounds to "NONE" through a script? The script could just follow the same steps as we do through GUI i.e open the sound settings then goto Sounds tab and so on. Or, there could be a more arcane way of doing this.

Comment: [maybe this - SU / change sound scheme via Windows Registry](https://superuser.com/questions/1300539/change-sound-scheme-in-windows-via-windows-registry/1397681)

Comment: I believe these settings are stored in the registry. So if you locate them, change the settings from the GUI, export the registry settings to a .reg file and you can just execute that .reg file on any computer to restore it.

Comment: ok, is it not possible to write a script that would repeat user actions done in the GUI?
Is registry a normal place to store something like sound settings?

Comment: Most if not all Windows settings are stored in registry, so modifying the correct registry value can change the sound settings, you can use reg add in elevated cmd to change registry through command line, and you can get the correct key and value by using procmon.